# How do i change linecolors of plotted curves from dataset in tikzpicture?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, database

im using pgfplots and was wondering why i cant change the color. I want to plot a set of data into a diagram as curves, but it seems that the colors seems unchangeable. the first curve in the data is always blue and the second red. But i want both same color e.g. green

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    filter discard warning=false,
    height=8cm,
    width=12cm,
    grid=major,
    legend entries={$a$, $b$},
    legend pos=north east
]

\addlegendimage{no markers,green}
\addlegendimage{no markers,green,dashed}
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}
    \datatable

\addplot table [x=I, y=$b_9$, mark=none, color=green] from \datatable;
\addplot table [x=I, y=$a_9$, mark=none, color=green, dashed] from 
\datatable;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

thnx in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try something like `\addplot[green] table ...`?

Comment: ur solution worked perfectly. Thnx for the fast help

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the syntax `\addplot[<color>]`, e.g. `\addplot[green]`. This will result in the line becoming green.

Just in comparison the way the TikZ `\draw` command works similarly: `\draw[green]` would also give a green line.